# Some Of The People

Tags: meaning

Does "Some of the people here might not come out alive"

=

"Some of the people here possibly are not going to come out alive."

"There is a possibility that some of the people here are not going to come out alive."

Are they the same?

I'm essentially asking if saying:

"5 people here possibly are not going to come out alive." is equivalent to "There is a possibility 5 people here are not going to come out alive."

Comment: The two sentences in your final example with "5 people" are not equivalent.

Comment: All your sentences with _some_ are valid for describing a dangerous situation, but how would a commentator know the exact number of likely deaths (unless there were only five people in there, in which case it would be worded differently)?

Answer (score 2):

The sentences you have mentioned in the post literally and fundamentally do share the same meaning, and none of the above is in charge of any grammatical or punctuational errors.

However, speaking of my point of view as a reader, the two sentences (here refers to the 'five people' ones) perhaps do have a slight difference in contention. You are emphasizing 'the five people are not going to come out alive' in the first sentence when you say 'Five people here possibly are not going to come out alive.' whereas the second sentence is implying the possible risk for the people who are considering doing this thing. It is focusing on the hazardousness of which, and the possibility of something unexpected uncontrollably occurring during the experiment or whatever you have mentioned that may result in the deaths of five people.

Even though the two sentences unequivocally mean the same thing, my brain still automatically tells me I am not going to be alive anymore after participating in this experiment or something when reading the first sentence, but I do feel a sparkle of hope when it comes to looking at the second sentence. I reckon this is due to the style of writing as the first sentence has a relatively subjective tone, while the second sentence has a more objective tone which makes the included information more credible and makes people feel less disconcerted. Moreover, the second sentence sounds more ambiguous in its way and which helps reduce people's attention on the estimated number of mortality, so they psychologically forget about the final consequence.

I hope this is helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things that one could be trying to say about these five people. Spelled out in a way that makes the difference clear, they are:

(1) For any one of the five, it is possible that that one will die.

(2) It is possible that all five will die.

(1) does not entail (2); there may be something about the situation that rules out the possibility of all five dying. To see that more clearly consider the fact that, although it is true that any holder of a lottery ticket can win, it is not possible for all of them to win.

The last sentence in the question expresses (2); all others express (1).

Although English language does have the resources to express the distinction between something like (1) and (2), in everyday contexts, people may not always be clear on whether they intend one or the other (and sometimes the difference may not be important to the overall point of the communication). Modal logic has a formal, symbolic language that makes it impossible to confuse them.